# check null before promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have this code sample in JS:

```html
  const [L, P, T ] = await Promise.all([
    client.getL(variable1),
    client.getF(variable2),
    client.getT(variable3),
  ]);
```

where i make a GET calls with variable1+2+3 is some sort of ID that i add to the request.
but, those ID can be null.
how is the best way to check if those variable1/2/3 is null and if so, dont make the make that call (and set the corresponding const to null), and combine it with promise.all?

for example, if variable1 is null, i want L to be null, and of course, the GET request should not execute ...

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const promises = [
  variable1 !== null ? client.getL(variable1) : null,
  variable2 !== null ? client.getF(variable2) : null,
  variable3 !== null ? client.getT(variable3) : null,
];

const [L, P, T] = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: this will insert null to L,P,T if variable1/2/3 is null?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to resolve the promise instead of making the request:

```js
const [L, P, T ] = await Promise.all([
    !variable1 ? Promise.resolve(null) : client.getL(variable1),
...
  ]);
```

Comment: We don't know the nature of `variable1`, if OP wants to filter `null` out, this answer will also remove `0`, `undefined` and other falsy values

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nullCheck helper function, like this:

```js
const nullCheck = (x, f) => x ?? f.apply(client, [x])

const [L, P, T] = await Promise.all([
  nullCheck(variable1, client.getL),
  nullCheck(variable2, client.getP),
  nullCheck(variable3, client.getT),
])
```

Note that it will check for both null and undefined, and return null or undefined respectively.

If you want to allow undefined variables to make function calls, instead use this function:

```js
const nullCheck = (x, f) => x===null ? null : f.apply(client, [x])
```

Answer (score 0):

Map an array of variables into an array of promises and destruct the result into result variables:

```
const [L, P, T] = await Promise.all([var1, var2, var3].map((v, idx) => v !== null ? client[`get${'LPT'[idx]}`](v) : null));
```

Comment: What is `method`?

Comment: @Bergi a silly refactoring leftover, fixed